# Tabbed screen with custom navigation in AppConKit 3

Tags: navigation, tabbar, navigationbar, appconkit

How to create a screen with multiple subscreens as tabs with a custom navigation bar using AppConKit 3?

In an app I want to have one screen with tab navigation. It's not a top screen.
This screen should have a custom navigationBar. How can I do it using AppConKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's generally not supported to have tabbars as NOT firstscreens in a navigation hierachy - especially on iOS this can cause serious issues on pre iOS 6  devices. 
If you want to show a tabbar as not the first screen in your app, show it modally (just add a true) to the showView.
Second, if you have navigation inside your tabs, you will want a separate navigation controller in each tab. So the layout for an app with two tabs you will have is :

- Screen with type Tabcontroller, containing:

  - Tab1 pointing to Tab1_Nav
  - Tab2 pointing to Tab2_Nav
- Screen Tab1_Nav type Navigation, Rootform set to Tab1_content
- Screen Tab2_Nav type Navigation, Rootform set to Tab2_content
- Screen Tab1_content type normal with a custom navbar and a bar button item.
- Screen Tab2_content

Hope this helps

[Edit]: in a modal navigation structure you can close the whole modal screen with the function dismissModal.

```
mobileController.activeController().dismissModal()
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! It worked for me! The only left question is how to add 'back' button to navbar and to connect it with a main screen, which is parent of Tabcontroller screen?

Comment: Where should I put this code? I can't find an action, which would be triggered when I press "back" button on navbar in Tab1_content. onGoBack action doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: There is no such action. As you are in a modal view, and a modal view opens a new navigation hierarchy, you can't go back. Just add a Barbutton on the left side with the dismiss action. The button won't be visible on android